# How to set contextName of log4j2 Mbean

Tags: java, jmx, log4j2

While accessing log4j2 Mbeans using jvisualvm, I see that the type (contextName) inside log4j2 package is a number (for me it is 1482868390). Since this goes in as 'type' while specifying Object in query, I would like to specify it to a more recognizable name that I prefer. Is there a way to set the contextName in xml configuration.
I think there is a way to do it for web applications, but I would like to set this for a standalone java application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible but not in configuration. You can achieve this by subclassing one of Log4j's ContextSelectors and overriding its   `defaultContextName()` method.

You then tell Log4j to use your ContextSelector by starting your application with system property `-DLog4jContextSelector=com.yourpackage.YourContextSelector`.

If you're making all loggers async, you want to subclass [AsyncLoggerContextSelector](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/xref/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/async/AsyncLoggerContextSelector.html#L56), otherwise [ClassLoaderContextSelector](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/xref/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/selector/ClassLoaderContextSelector.html#L187).